# Ethereum mempool transaction of Uncle and Fork nodes

Tags: transactions, txpool, uncle-blocks

In the Bitcoin network when a fork happens, the block transactions from the shortest chain are reinserted again into the mempool.

In Ethereum instead we have Uncle blocks and Fork blocks. What happens to the Uncle block transactions, are they reinserted again into the mempool or the transactions remain confirmed and part of the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

If the block is included as an Uncle, then the transactions remain confimed. If not, they return to the mempool, as far as i know.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any reference I can look at? (I've looked at the official Yellow paper but there is no mention, as far as I know)